# Random Number for Each Row in DataFrame in Spark

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I am reading two tables from hive into dataframes and want to associate a unique number to the rows present in both the data frames. The number should be unique within the data frame and also in both the data frames.

I read about using `row_source()` function while querying from hive , but the number wont be unique for the two data frames.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

One Thing That You can do is make a UDF that generates the Random number and add another Column ID which is made using this UDF and , your UDF can differentiate the Column id with a prefix ,

For example for **dataFrame1** it would be like **df1::121237814** and for **dataFrame2** it would be like **df2::65452634827**

So your UDF can somewhat looks like this:

```
def generateIdForDF1=df1::UUID.randomUUID.hashCode.toLong
```

And same goes for the other one !

Comment: I want to use that value for some fields, and it cant be any junk value , it can be integer only.

Comment: Then what you can do is UUID.randomUUID.hashCode.toLong or UUID.randomUUID.hashCode.toInt can be used

Comment: hashcode doesnt guarantee unique code for any object. Even the best hashcode algo gives the guarantee of 95 percent for unique hashcode. so this way wont work out most probably because my use case deals with billions of rows.

Comment: Then i think what you can do is you can take out the RDD and use the zipWithIndex function to assign a unique value to every Row, reform the dataFrame and from the updated RDD and use it afterwords, 
but let me warn you , it will shuffle the data a lot , and it will take much time

Comment: zipWithIndex needs to be explored. It does shuffling?

Comment: It shuffles the data on a very large scale and hence I suggested you the UUID part , because I have faced this problem already and for such a large data 95 % was OK for me until it breaks the whole application for FutureTImeouts  and take a hell lot of time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125780/discussion-between-aviral-kumar-and-shivansh-srivastava).